# Migrating UberSVN data to the new Wandisco Subversion ( Windows 7 )

Tags: svn, ubersvn

I am currently tasked to migrate the data and repositories of a UberSVN with the version 1.6.18 to another computer. The employee before me did not save the installer for the UberSVN and now Wandisco has discontinued the Apache UbserSVN. If we pursue on still using Wandisco, I will have to use their latest Subversion but I don't know if it is possible to migrate UberSVN to their new subversions. I am also open to using other Subversions if it is possible to migrate UberSVN to them.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get UberSVN installer from any official source anymore since it has been discontinued for a couple of years already. If the server computer is on Windows, take a closer look at VisualSVN Server: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/ And here is the how-to instruction about importing your existing repositories: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/. BTW, you can check the complete list of Subversion binary packages at http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html.

Answer (score 1):

UberSVN doesn't change the repository format so migrating the repo data to another Subversion solution shouldn't be difficult. However UberSVN won't be easily able to run a later Subversion server version than that supported at the time of the last release.

There are alternatives out there if you are looking for something to manage the entire Subversion environment, or you can use WANdisco's binaries if you are comfortable installing them, configuring Apache etc.

Ian